# Как найти элемент "a" с самым большим индексом?

Tags: python, list, индексация

У меня дан список, например `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'n', 'a']` и мне надо найти элемент `"a"` с самым большим индексом.

Этот код выведет `0`:

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'n', 'a']
print(list.index('a')) #выведет 0
```

А мне надо, чтобы элемент `"a"` с наибольшим индексом.

Comment: вы, конечно, не поверите, но искомый элемент тоже в точности равен `a`. главное: даже искать не надо.

Comment: list = [a,b,c,d,a,b,n,a]                                                                                                               
           print(list.index('a'))#выведет 0, а мне надо чтоб элемент "a" с наибольшим индексом

Comment: Ищите с конца...

Comment: `len(itemlist) - itemlist[-1::-1].index('a') - 1`

Comment: Учись правильно формулировать проблему - не "найти элемент а с самым большим индексом", а "найти самый большой индекс элемента а".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот один из вариантов кода

```
sp=['a',1,2,'a','c','a', 'foo', 'bar']
for i in range(0, len(sp)):
    if sp[i]=='a':
        x=i
print(x)
```

Вывод (*индекс элемента*):

```
5
```

Метод рабочий)

Comment: `for i in reversed(range(0, len(sp))): if sp[i]=='a': break`

Comment: поиск 'x' завершается ошибкой

Comment: рабочий, но не оптимальный

Answer (score 1):

Универсальная версия, под разные символы.

```
def foo(need_symbol, simple_list):
    all_max_pos = {}
    for i, pos in zip(simple_list, range(0, len(simple_list))):
        all_max_pos[i] = pos
    print(f'Max index is = {all_max_pos[need_symbol]}')


def choose(simple_list):
    print(simple_list)
    print("pick symbol for show max index:")
    need_symbol = input("Put symbol here ==>    ")
    return need_symbol

def main():
    simple_list = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","n","a"]
    need_symbol = choose(simple_list)
    foo(need_symbol, simple_list)


main()
```

Comment: `zip(simple_list, range(0, len(simple_list)))` ну enumerate же есть, зачем такую жесть городить

Comment: Хорошее замечание. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальный алгоритм будет если вы просто переберёте индексы от конца списка до начала, используя подходящий вариант вызова функции `range`. Останов алгоритма при первом же подходящем найденном индексе:

```py
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'n', 'a']
for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
    if lst[i] == 'a':
        print(i)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Для разнообразия - через `index()` с обработкой исключений:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'n', 'a']
i, element = -1, 'a'
while True:
    try:
        i = lst.index(element, i + 1)
    except:
        print(f'Максимальный индекс для элемента `{element}` = {i}' if i > -1 else f'Элемент `{element}` не найден в списке')
        break
```

```
Максимальный индекс для элемента `a` = 7
```